# The 1st approximation of multi-viables which contains the differential

Tags: approximation

When I input to Mathematica as following,

```
M = 2;
u = { x0, x1 };
g = {{ 1 + h00[x0,x1], h01[x0,x1] }, { h01[x0,x1], 1 + h11[x0,x1] } };
giraw = Inverse[g];
gi = Simplify[ giraw ];
svrs = { h00[x0,x1], h01[x0,x1], h11[x0,x1] };
giFst = Normal[ Series[ gi /. Thread[ svrs -> t * svrs ], {t, 0, 1} ]] /. t -> 1 ;
Chr1raw = Table[(D[g[[l,j]], u[[i]]] + D[g[[i,l]], u[[j]]] - D[g[[i,j]], u[[l]]])/2,
    {l,M}, {i,M}, {j,M} ];
Chr1 = Simplify[ Chr1raw ];
Chr2raw =Table[Sum[ giFst[[k,l]] * Chr1[[l,i,j]], {l,M} ], {k,M}, {i,M}, {j,M} ];
Chr2 = Simplify[ Chr2raw ];
svrs2 = {h00, h01, h11,D[h00[x0,x1],x0], D[h01[x0,x1],x0], D[h11[x0,x1],x0],
  D[h00[x0,x1],x1], D[h01[x0,x1],x1], D[h11[x0,x1],x1]};
Chr2Fst = Normal[ Series[ Chr2 /. Thread[ svrs2 -> t2 * svrs2 ], {t2, 0, 1} ]] /. t2 -> 1
```

the output from Mathematica is as followings.

```
{{{Derivative[1, 0][h00][x0, x1]/2 - (h00[x0, x1]*Derivative[1, 0][h00][x0, x1])/2 + 
  (h01[x0, x1]*(Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1] - 2*Derivative[1, 0][h01][x0, x1]))/2, 
  Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1]/2 - (h00[x0, x1]*Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1])/2 -
  (h01[x0, x1]*Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1])/2}, 
  {Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1]/2 - (h00[x0, x1]*Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1])/2 -
  (h01[x0, x1]*Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1])/2, 
  Derivative[0, 1][h01][x0, x1] - (h01[x0, x1]*Derivative[0, 1][h11][x0, x1])/2 + 
  h00[x0, x1]*(-Derivative[0, 1][h01][x0, x1] + Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]/2) -
  Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]/2}}, 
  {{-(h01[x0, x1]*Derivative[1, 0][h00][x0, x1])/2 + (h11[x0, x1]*(Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1] -
  2*Derivative[1, 0][h01][x0, x1]))/2 + 
  (-Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1] + 2*Derivative[1, 0][h01][x0, x1])/2,
  -(h01[x0, x1]*Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1])/2 + 
  Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]/2 - (h11[x0, x1]*Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1])/2}, 
  {-(h01[x0, x1]*Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1])/2 + Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]/2 -
  (h11[x0, x1]*Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1])/2, 
  Derivative[0, 1][h11][x0, x1]/2 - (h11[x0, x1]*Derivative[0, 1][h11][x0, x1])/2 + 
  (h01[x0, x1]*(-2*Derivative[0, 1][h01][x0, x1] + Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]))/2}}}
```

However, I don't expect this output.
I expect output like the following which cut off the 2nd approximate parts.

```
{{{Derivative[1, 0][h00][x0, x1]/2, Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1]/2},
   {Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1]/2, 
   Derivative[0, 1][h01][x0, x1] - Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]/2}}, 
   {{(-Derivative[0, 1][h00][x0, x1] + 2*Derivative[1, 0][h01][x0, x1])/2,
   Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]/2}, 
   {Derivative[1, 0][h11][x0, x1]/2, Derivative[0, 1][h11][x0, x1]/2}}}
```

To obtain the output that I expect,
what input should I give to Mathematica?

I am looking forward to your advice.

Comment: Can you read your own post?

Comment: Do you know the method how to post outputs of mathematica which are including very complex data? I just have copied and pasted the output of mathematica to the post form. If you know the method, please tell me the method. Must I create image files?

Comment: @Belisarius, I tried to paste output like this into an answer but got the same sort ot unreadable form.  How can it be improved?  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey et al. -- `InputForm`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yup. That's it

Comment: @MichaelE2 `InputForm`, or often just copying, works well in most instances, but not for the output shown in this question.  For instance, `1/2 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(h00\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)` is not very helpful.  Perhaps, LaTex would be better. $\frac{1}{2} \text{h00}^{(1,0)}$

Comment: @bbgodfrey `InputForm` did the trick for me. I get `Derivative[1, 0][h00][x0, x1]/2`, which can be copied and used in *M*.

Comment: @MichaelE2, I was copying the output as `InputText`, not converting it to `InputForm` (by `%//InputForm`) and then copying it.  Evidently, the two are not the same.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @NaotaInamoto, I have reformatted your question to make it easier to read.  However, I recommend that you edit it to provide a clear description of what you are trying to accomplish, so that others can attempt to assist you.

Comment: Your `svrs2` might not be what you expect, and this could cause the result to have more terms than expected.

Comment: At this case, I did a careless mistake. The case of the multiple variables which includes complex numbers of the high dimension doesn't go successfully. I missed the simplification of the high dimension case including complex numbers to the two dimensions example which don't include complex numbers. I am going to verify the input about the high dimension case including complex numbers now.

Answer (score 2):

What Daniel Lichtblau is hinting at:

```
svrs2 = {h00[x0, x1], h01[x0, x1], h11[x0, x1], D[h00[x0, x1], x0], 
  D[h01[x0, x1], x0], D[h11[x0, x1], x0], D[h00[x0, x1], x1], 
  D[h01[x0, x1], x1], D[h11[x0, x1], x1]};
```

The first three terms are missing their arguments in the OP's code.  Fixing this mistake leads to the desired output.